# Monitor CPU Usage of Other Processes

Tags: c, windows, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm looking to create a C program that can check the CPU usage of any process currently running, specifically to check if any program goes over a certain percent value. How would I go about getting this sort of info about other programs? (On Windows)

All the help I can find online only mentions the CPU usage of the current program.

Comment: I'm not a windows guy myself, but I believe you are looking for [performance counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/performance-counters-portal?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @Jason exactly. .net has even high level assembly for that